# How to restore bolt state during failover

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying to figure out how to restore the state of a storm bolt intance during failover. I can persist the state externally (DB or file system), however once the bolt instance is restarted I need to point to the specific state of that bolt instance to recover it. 
The prepare method of a bolt receives a context, documented here http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/task/TopologyContext.html

What is not clear to me is - is there any piece of this context that uniquely identifies the specific bolt instance so I can understand which persistent state to point to? Is that ID preserved during failover? Alternatively, is there any variable/object I can set for the specific bolt/instance that is preserved during failover? Any help appreciated!

br
Sib

P.S.
New to stackoverflow so pls bear with me...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look for [Trident](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-state) Its basically an abstraction built on top of storm . The documentation says

> Trident has first-class abstractions for reading from and writing to stateful sources. The state can either be internal to the topology – e.g., kept in-memory and backed by HDFS – or externally stored in a database like Memcached or Cassandra

In case of any fail over it says

> Trident manages state in a fault-tolerant way so that state updates are idempotent in the face of retries and failures.

You can go through the documentation for any further clarification.

Comment: Tx for that - I'll dig the docs. At a glance, it looks like I can persist state "by transactions". That looks good as long as trident is used for processing. What I'm trying to do is embedding a 3pp in a bolt, and the 3pp has its own state persistency. I would like to restore the state when the bolt restarts, so everything I have to do is take a note of where the state is and be notified at restart. I'll go through the trident API in details and post again.

Answer (score 0):

Tx (and credit) to Storm user group!

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201312.mbox/%3C74083558E4509844944FF5CF2BA7B20F1060FD0E@ESESSMB305.ericsson.se%3E

Answer (score 0):

In original Storm, both `spout` and `bolt` are stateless. Storm can managed to restart nodes but it will require some effort to restore the states of nodes. There are two solutions that I can think of:

1. If a message fails to process, Storm will replay it from **ROOT** of the topology and the logic of `replay` has to be implemented by user. So in this case I would like to put more state information (e.g. the ID of some external state storage and id of this task) in messages.
2. Or you can use `Trident`. It can provides `txid` to each transaction and simplify storage process.

I'm OK with first solution because my app doesn't require transactional operations and I have a better understanding of the original Storm (Storm generates simpler log than Trident does).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [task ID](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/storm-user/7P23beQIL4c/HrgDyR_BwfwJ).

> Task ids are assigned at topology creation and are static. If a task dies/restarts or gets reassigned somewhere else, it will still have the same id.